# PHP вызов метода класса

Tags: php

Допустим есть класс:

```
class Foo
{        
      public $W;
      function __construct(){$this->W = "true";}
      function GetW(){echo $this->W;}
}

$t = new Foo();
$t->GetW();
```

Тут все ясно, когда создаю объект, то конструктор инициализирует свойство `$W` и выведит его значение - true.

А если не создавать экземпляр класса `$t = new Foo();`, а вызвать метод `GetW` таким образом:

```
Foo::GetW();
```

Будет ли в этом случае вызываться конструктор?

Answer (score 2):

1. Foo::GetW(); в данном случае выведет ошибку, потому что GetW() должен быть статическим методом
2. Конструктор вызываться не будет, так как вы не создаете экземпляр класса, а работаете в контексте самого класса

Answer (score 1):

Так вызвать метод не получиться, если только при описании метода добавить ему слово static, тогда его вызвать получиться.  
пример:

`public static function GetW(){echo $this->W;}`

но и тут возникнут проблемы, потому что свойство W не может существовать без экземпляра класса, т.е. нужно обязательно создать объект. Но если написать так:

`public static $W;
public static function GetW(){echo self::$W;}`

то все сработает.

Ну и если вызвать таким образом метод, то конструктор не будет вызываться.

Так же можно получить доступ к этому свойству таким образом и повторить операцию статического метода без самого метода:

`echo Foo::W`